# Correct modeling in Redis for writing single entity but querying multiple

Tags: redis

I'm trying to convert data which is on a Sql DB to Redis. In order to gain much higher throughput because it's a very high throughput. I'm aware of the downsides of persistence, storage costs etc...

So, I have a table called "Users"  with few columns. Let's assume: ID, Name, Phone, Gender

Around 90% of the requests are Writes. to update a single row. 
Around 10% of the requests are Reads. to get 20 rows in each request.

I'm trying to get my head around the right modeling of this in order to get the max out of it.

If there were only updates - I would use Hashes. 
But because of the 10% of Reads I'm afraid it won't be efficient.

Any suggestions?

Comment: An excellent question! I have the same concerns.  Anyone has thoughts on this matter?

Comment: "to get 20 rows in each request." is it last 20 rows, random 20 rows, particular 20 rows?

Comment: Leave the reading with the SQL database? Do the writes via redis and update the SQL DB as required?  Is losing some of the writes an issue? Will need some investigation and more complex.

Comment: 1. 20 different rows each time. Depending on the request. 2.I'm trying to avoid Sql totally. But  your direction is an option. 3. I can afford losing some of the writes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the real question is whether you need to support partial updates.

Supposing partial update is not required, you can store your record in a blob associated to a key (i.e. string datatype). All write operations can be done in one roundtrip, since the record is always written at once. Several read operations can be done in one rountrip as well using the MGET command.

Now, supposing partial update is required, you can store your record in a dictionary associated to a key (i.e. hash datatype). All write operations can be done in one roundtrip (even if they are partial). Several read operations can also be done in one roundtrip provided HGETALL commands are [pipelined](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining).

Pipelining several HGETALL commands is a bit more CPU consuming than using MGET, but not that much. In term of latency, it should not be significantly different, except if you execute hundreds of thousands of them per second on the Redis instance.

Comment: Thanks. Updates -  one user sends an update on his own status  with several properties. (partial update)  .   Reads- one user requests data about 20 users, Needs all their properties. Most of the actions are the writes.